# How do I align dropboxes regardless of the length of the labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I'm using rails and I have  and then <%= select ...>. But there are three rows of this and the dropboxes start right after the label ends and the labels are all of different lengths so the dropboxes are not aligned. I'm not really sure what part of my code I need to change to set how they are aligned. CSS? I have some ideas (creating a table, making a class etc.) but they're not working so I was hoping someone could let me know what direction to go in.

Comment: yep, just add some styling in css

Comment: Add in your stylesheets something like this: label {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Put a class onto your label tags, then in the css for that class you need to:

1. add a fixed width that is larger than the largest label
2. make sure the label has "display: inline-block" or "display: block"
   because it needs to behave like a block-style (rather than a
   span-style) object to force widths on most displays.